# How to mount a single file in a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize a PHP application. In the dockerfile, I download the archive, extract it, etc.

Everything works fine. However, if a new version gets released and I update the dockerfile, I have to reinstall the application, because the config.php gets overwritten.

So I thought I can mount the file as a volume, like I do with the database.

I tried it two ways, with a volume and a direct path.

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: src
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      -  app-conf:/var/www/html/upload
      -  app-conf:/var/www/html/config.php
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: mysql
      DB_MANAGER: MysqlManager

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
      MYSQL_DATABASE:
      MYSQL_USER:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:

volumes:
  mysqldata:
  app-conf:
```

Which results in the error:

And I tried it with a given path, as a mounted volume.

```
/src/docker/myapp/upload:/var/www/html/upload
/src/docker/myapp/upload:/var/www/html/config.php
```

However, both ways are not working. With the mounted volume, I see that upload gets created.

But then it fails with:

> /var/www/html/config.php\" caused \"not a directory\"""

If I try it with

```
/src/docker/myapp/upload/config.php:/var/www/html/config.php
```

Docker creates the upload folder and then a config.php folder. Not a file.

Or is there another way to persist the config?

Comment: In my case, I simple that to "touch" an empty file before creating the container/volume. If the file didn't exist, it created a directory.

Comment: If there are contents in the container file in the image and if you `touch` the host file before binding the volume as a file, the image version of the file is overwritten with an empty file. Is there a way to bind the container file to a file on the host and "get out" the existing data in the container file?

Answer (score 711, accepted):

> ## TL;DR/Notice:
>
> If you experience a directory being created in place of the file you are trying to mount, you have probably failed to supply a **valid** and **absolute** path. This is a common mistake with a silent and confusing failure mode.

File volumes are done this way in docker (absolute path example (can use env variables), and you need to mention the file name) :

```
volumes:
  - /src/docker/myapp/upload:/var/www/html/upload
  - /src/docker/myapp/upload/config.php:/var/www/html/config.php
```

You can also do:

```
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/upload:/var/www/html/upload
  - ${PWD}/upload/config.php:/var/www/html/config.php
```

If you fire the docker-compose from `/src/docker/myapp` folder

Comment: Like I said, if I try

    /src/docker/myapp/upload/config.php:/var/www/html/config.php

Docker creates the upload folder and then a config.php folder. Not a file.

Comment: In your post you wrote differently. If the file is there it should mount as file.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume <- should be defenitely working

Comment: In order for this to work I had to supply an absolute path. The tip using PWD helped a lot here, thanks!

Comment: For me is creating a folder rather than the files, but I think because that file is copied later in that path is there anyway to postpone the binding?

Comment: if /src/docker/myapp/upload/config.php doesn't exists in the host docker will create a folder... What i'm doing is creating a script that creates an empty file before running docker run - would be ideal if I can instruct docker to do it for me via cmd line args.

Comment: Though it worked when the container already exist but in a fresh new instance when doing so I am getting the *ERROR: Duplicate mount points: issue*

Comment: My solution was even better - make sure the file you're trying to mount actually exists! If it doesnt, it will throw this error since it tries to create a directory with the given file name.

Comment: Windows users will want to call `set PWD=%CD%` before calling `docker-compose up` to populate the `PWD` variable.

Comment: use `$(pwd)` instead of `${PWD}` on linux

Comment: If it initially created a folder for you, make sure to stop and remove the problematic container so it can clean the folder and map the file from the host.

Comment: If ${PWD} doesn't work. It might be you're using sudo. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41948354/4123703)

Comment: my problem is that even after ensuring that the host file exists (and mirrors the container file) I'm still getting a "not a directory" error because it was created as directory once. there must be some way to reset this, because before the host file was deleted it was working exactly with this config.

Comment: Just use relative paths ` - ./src/foo:/etc/foo` as PWD is undefined on windows and `-/` works on Linux and Windows. Paths are relative to the docker file.

Comment: Works fine with relative paths ` - ./php.custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.custom.ini`

Comment: How would the thing be easier if the docker would just refuse to start the container if the volume doesn't exist. With a helpful message. Wouldn't it? All this would be unnecessary and many directories owned by "root" under my user account would not be created. (E.g. for dev, mount "${PWD}/storage" into  the container, but it didn't exist. Now it exists, owned by root, because docker creates it.)

Comment: Here is an example why docker should not throw error when host path does exists: `docker run --rm --network none -v $(pwd)/a/b/c:/a/b/c -it alpine/make mkdir -p /a/b/c/d/e/f`

it should create a dir (in host `pwd`) like `a/b/c/d/e/f`. You don't need to `mkdir -p a/b/c` before `docker run`.

`a/b/c` is not created yet, so docker will not know it's a file or dir, or just not created yet, so it assumes it should be a dir (best guess, most of the time that's the case).

Answer (score 153):

I had been suffering from a similar issue. I was trying to import my config file to my container so that I can fix it every time I need without re-building the image.

I mean I thought the below command would map `$(pwd)/config.py` from Docker host to `/root/app/config.py` into the container as a file.

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/config.py:/root/app/config.py my_docker_image
```

However, it always created a directory named `config.py`, not a file.

while looking for clue, I found the reason(from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#differences-between--v-and---mount-behavior))

> If you use -v or --volume to bind-mount a file or directory that does
>   not yet exist on the Docker host, -v will create the endpoint for you.
>   *It is always created as a directory*.

Therefore, it is always created as a directory because my docker host does not have `$(pwd)/config.py`.

Even if I create config.py in docker host. 
`$(pwd)/config.py` just overwirte `/root/app/config.py` not exporting `/root/app/config.py`.

Comment: I just added a `touch path/to/file` in the `Dockerfile`so that when I mount it would still be a file (not a created dir)

Comment: left side of `:` has to be full path. It works this way

Comment: The `touch` was the answer, do that in Dockerfile then your docker-compose volume mount will work correctly without creating a directory

Comment: And don't forget to `mkdir -p /path/to/file` for good measure before `touch /path/to/file`

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue for my case. I use './docker/uploads.ini:/usr/...' but the docker-compose file in in docker folder.

So I change to './uploads.ini:/usr/...' and it works.

Answer (score 152):

The way that worked for me is to use a `bind` mount

```
  version: "3.7"    
  services:
  app:
    image: app:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./sourceFile.yaml
        target: /location/targetFile.yaml
```

Thanks mike breed for the answer over at: [Mount single file from volume using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657370/mount-single-file-from-volume-using-docker-compose)

You need to use the "long syntax" to express a `bind` mount using the `volumes` key: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-3

Comment: This answer is way more concise than the above and did exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't work in case of file is created in container, it throws `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist`

Answer (score 103):

Use **mount** (`--mount`) instead **volume** (`-v`)

More info: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

## Example:

Ensure /tmp/a.txt exists on docker host

```
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/a.txt,target=/root/a.txt alpine sh
```

Comment: Thank you Subbu, @Jakub Juszczak this should be the accepted answer, it's the only answer that answers the question at all, and it worked for me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. *volumes* will work as well (because the issue is in absolute path). The only difference between `--mount` and `-v` is behavior when host part of the volume doesn't exist yet. As per your link:
>If you use -v or --volume to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, -v creates the endpoint for you. It is always created as a directory.

Comment: I do not know how to translate this into a docker-compose. 'Little help?

Answer (score 43):

As of docker-compose file version 3.2, you can **specify a volume mount of type "bind"** (instead of the default type "volume") that allows you to mount a single file into the container. Search for "bind mount" in the docker-compose volume docs:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

In my case, I was trying to mount a single ".secrets" file into my application that contained secrets for local development and testing only. In production, my application fetches these secrets from AWS instead.

If I mounted this file as a volume using the shorthand syntax:

```yaml
volumes:
 - ./.secrets:/data/app/.secrets
```

Docker would create a ".secrets" *directory* inside the container instead of mapping to the file outside of the container. My code would then raise an error like "IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '.secrets'".

I fixed this by using the long-hand syntax instead, specifying my secrets file using a read-only "bind" volume mount:

```yaml
volumes:
 - type: bind
   source: ./.secrets
   target: /data/app/.secrets
   read_only: true
```

Now Docker correctly mounts my .secrets file into the container, creating a file inside the container instead of a directory.

Comment: I have the same error also by specifying a "bind" volume mount, any source is mounted as a directory

Comment: The file still needs to be created.

Answer (score 36):

**All above answers are Correct.**

but one thing that I found really helpful is that **mounted file should exist inside docker host in advance** otherwise docker will create a directory instead.

for example:

```
/a/file/inside/host/hostFile.txt:/a/file/inside/container/containerFile.txt
```

`hostFile.txt` should exist in advance.
otherwise you will receive this error: `containerFile.txt is a directory`

Answer (score 32):

For anyone using Windows container like me, know that you CANNOT bind or mount single files using windows container.

> The following examples will fail when using Windows-based containers, as the destination of a volume or bind mount inside the container must be one of: a non-existing or empty directory; or a drive other than C:. Further, **the source of a bind mount must be a local directory, not a file**.
>
> `net use z: \\remotemachine\share`
>
> `docker run -v z:\foo:c:\dest ...`
>
> `docker run -v \\uncpath\to\directory:c:\dest ...`
>
> `docker run -v c:\foo\somefile.txt:c:\dest ...`
>
> `docker run -v c:\foo:c: ...`
>
> `docker run -v c:\foo:c:\existing-directory-with-contents ...`

It's hard to spot but [it's there](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only)

[Link to the Github issue regarding mapping files into Windows container](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30555)

Comment: Do you know if it is still the case in july 2020 ?

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan Yes. According a comment from a docker developer on the issue, it's preferable to mount directory anyway, even on linux. They also said they cannot allow this behavior without a massive rewrite. So I really doubt we will see this in the short-medium term.

Comment: We faced the same scenario. But in K8s it allowed mounting as a destination file from conigMap entry. Link to repo in case anyone is interested. https://github.com/ms-azure-demos/aks-windows-container-configmap-file-mount-powershell

Answer (score 21):

You can also use a relative path in your `docker-compose.yml` file like this (tested on Windows host, Linux container):

```yml
volumes:
    - ./test.conf:/fluentd/etc/test.conf
```

Comment: I tested this on Mac with `version: '3.7'` specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file with docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b, and it worked.

Comment: I still get a directory instead of a file.

Comment: @chovy have a look on this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66327349/10539792

Comment: And read that line over and over. I'm consistent in trying to map `.env` as `./env:/app.env` and forgetting the dot (so instead of `./.env:/app.env`). I think because I already typed it (to specify current dir) my muscle memory does not want to add the second dot.. :-P

Answer (score 5):

In compose I am using a relative path and it works:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
    svc1: 
      volumes:
        # Current dir is parent of src
        - "./src/file.conf:/path/in/container/file.conf
```

Using `docker run` command to bind mount a file produces:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'path/file.conf' mount path must be absolute. 
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Apparently the only way to do this is to specify an absolute mount path like this:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --mount type=bind,source="/path/to/file.conf",target=/file.conf alpine sh
```

also using `"%cd%"` for **Windows Users** or  `"$(pwd)"` for **Linux Users** is a way to deal with absolute paths.

see [storage bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

> For Visual Studio Code Users make sure you are running the %cd% command in a Command Prompt Terminal, not PowerShell.

Answer (score 5):

**TL&DR:**  Docker defaults all mount points to directories. If you want to make sure your file is mounted into your docker instance, the file must already exist prior to docker-compose up and running.

**Explanation:**

Traditionally, the purpose of mounting a volume has always meant mounting a storage location to a directory.  However, that is now changing with the ability to now just share files. From a programmer's perspective, its hard to know whether a "/tmp/something" is a file or a directory.  Docker, therefore, assumes all mount points are first a directory unless the file already exists.

In your example if you want a file to be mounted, make sure it already exists on the host system. When Docker sees that this entry already exists it will mount the file into the docker environment.

Answer (score 4):

Be carefull if you use docker context to operate with docker on remote virtual machine. In this case the file you trying to mount will certanly not exist on target VM. Thus you not existed file will be mount as folder.

Comment: This is a great comment

Comment: This is my situation - but what should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: @david-montgomery, you should change your approach or move the mounted files to the remote machine or place them to the docker image

Comment: Yeah I was doing that already, I misunderstood what this question was saying @falko

Answer (score 3):

You can mount files or directories/folders it all depends on Source file or directory. And also you need to provide full path or if you are not sure you can use PWD. Here is a simple working example.

In this example, I am mounting env-commands file which already exists in my working directory

```
$ docker run  --rm -it -v ${PWD}/env-commands:/env-commands aravindgv/eosdt:1.0.5 /bin/bash -c "cat /env-commands"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, docker-compose was creating a directory instead of a file, then crashing mid-way.

what i did :

1. run the container without mapping the file
2. copy the config file to the host location :

   docker cp containername:/var/www/html/config.php ./config.php
3. remove the container (docker-compose down)
4. put the mapping back and remount up the container

docker compose will find the config file, and will map that instead of trying to create a directory.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 answer, on Mac with Minikube/Hyperkit docker and Docker Compose**

Since I'm not using Docker Desktop any longer, I've experienced numerous issues similar to "docker in docker (dind)" paradigm with minikube...

1. **mount minikube**
2. **use absolute path**

e.g., easiest way was to mount the exact home path...

```sh
minikube mount $HOME:/Users/<you>

... keeps running...
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
volumes:
      - /Users/<you>/path/to/file.yaml:/somedir/file.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I had a broken symbolic link on the file I was trying to mount into the container

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on my Windows 8.1

It turned out that it was due to case-sensitivity of path.
I called `docker-compose up` from directory `cd /c/users/alex/` and inside container a file was turned into directory.

But when I did `cd /c/Users/alex/` (not Users capitalized) and called `docker-compose up` from there, it worked.

In my system both Users dir and Alex dir are capitalized, though it seems like only Users dir matter.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, 
if you need the a ${PWD} env variable in your docker-compose.yml you can creat a .env file in the same directory as your docker-compose.yml file then insert manualy the location of your folder.

CMD (pwd_var.bat) :

```
echo PWD=%cd% >> .env
```

Powershell (pwd_var.ps1) :

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'; echo "PWD=$(get-location).path" >> .env
```

There is more good features hear for docker-compose .env variables:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/ especially for the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` env variable that allow docker compose to accept windows path with baskslash `"\"`.

When you want to share a file on windows, the file must exist before sharing it with the container.

Comment: You can not use PowerShell with docker, it creates a vendor lock-in and hurts the community...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone.

I had this problem and tried everything. Volume bindings looked well and even if I mounted directory (not files), I had the file names in the mounted directory correctly but mounted as dirs.

I tried to re-enable shared drives and Docker complained the firewall is active.

After disabling the firewall all was working fine.

Comment: Thank you for that! Your post made me realize that my selinux was set to enforcing and that was causing all of my troubles. Don't know why you were down-voted ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to happen if you forget to actually include the file you want to mount in the source dir. I learned the hard way. No error message such as 'file not present', instead creates a directory in the destination.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on Windows, `Docker 18.06.1-ce-win73 (19507)`.

Removing and re-adding the shared drive via the Docker settings panel and everything worked again.

Answer (score -1):

For myself, the issue was that I specified the incorrect source file.

Here's an example:

```
 robert ❱ ~ ❱ docker run --rm -it -v "${PWD}/non-existant:/root/destination" -w /root --entrypoint /usr/bin/ls ubuntu -lad destination
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 64 Mar 29 05:54 destination
 robert ❱ ~ ❱ touch exists
 robert ❱ ~ ❱ docker run --rm -it -v "${PWD}/exists:/root/destination" -w /root --entrypoint /usr/bin/ls ubuntu -lad destination
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 29 05:58 destination
 robert ❱ ~ ❱
```

TL;DR - It could be your spelling as it was for me.