# Persistent /etc/passwd on a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, mount, passwd, volumes

I have create a docker image that allows users to connect on it with SSH.

For security reason, I'd like to users can change their password. I only use docker named volumes, so I can't bind /etc/passwd and I don't want to mount all /etc

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you don't make a default password and they can connect and change it in the container? (or you can say ADD myfolder/passwd /etc/passwd in the dockerfile - but then you should be careful with this file - or just just create a script that runs at start and reads the password from another path and change it in passwd)

Comment: Yes users will change their password after logged in with ssh. But if I rebuild my image or restart (and not revive) my container, all passwords will be lost. So I can save the /etc/passwd file and restore it after but I don't like this way. Nothing cleaner?

Comment: try this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#read-more-about-docker-secret-commands

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the proper way to do that. But it seems too disproportionate for my use. I found a solution, see my own question response.

Comment: this has nothing to do with programming and should be on [su]

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found this solution:

- create a named volume
- mount it (for instance in /users)
- set a shadow file on it
- at start of the container, make a link for /users/shadow on /etc/shadow

Answer (score 0):

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248198/how-to-mount-a-single-file-in-a-volume/47099098) someone asks if it is possible to mount a file as a volume with docker compose (and the answer was yes), so if it is possible to do it with compose i think that this is possible also with docker.
I know it is different from your question because in they use host directories/files, but the docker named volumes (as you can see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)) are used to make the container host independent, this is done creating some volumes handled by docker.

So try to crate a volume and mount that volume in the place of the passwd file.

Comment: Thanks. But I believe the volume syntax starting by a '/' is for bind mounts with docker host and no for docker named volumes. Doing the following: `docker volume create passwd && docker container run -ti --mount source=passwd,target=/etc/passwd alpine` fail with: _docker: Error response from daemon: readdirent: not a directory._