# How to run docker mounting volumes using Docker engine SDK and Golang

Tags: docker, go, docker-api, docker-engine

I have being reviewing the docker engine SDK documentation related with running Docker with Golang (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/)
I would like to run a container(which is well documented) but I cannot find how can I mount a volume when running the container.

My idea is to use Docker SDK to run the equivalent command:
`docker run -v $PWD:/tmp myimage`
But without executing the Golang os exec library.

Is that possible?

Comment: There are a couple of mount options in the [`HostConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker@v20.10.21+incompatible/api/types/container#HostConfig) structure; is this the piece you're missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples section has most of what you need:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/#run-a-container

Important to remember that `docker run ...` does both

1. create a container
2. start a container

and that `docker run -v` [is short hand for](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount) `docker run --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app`

```golang
    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: "alpine",
        Cmd:   []string{"echo", "hello world",},
      },
      &container.HostConfig{
        Mounts: []mount.Mount{
          {
             Type: mount.TypeBind,
             Source: "/local/dir",
             Target: "/app",
          },
        },
     },
     nil,
     "",
   )
```

If you want just a single file

```golang
    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: "alpine",
        Cmd:   []string{"echo", "hello world",},
      },
      &container.HostConfig{
        Binds: []string{
          "/local/dir/file.txt:/app/file.txt",
        },
      },
      nil,
      "",
   )
```

related:

- [How to mount a single file in a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42248198/4526019)
- https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient/issues/132
- [Defining a mount point for volumes in GoLang Docker SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48470194/4526019)