# Docker map an external config file

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I want to make an external config file via volume and pass it like:

`docker run MyImage -v /home/path/my_config.conf:folder2/`(is that right btw?)

But have no idea how to link this volume to the argument for the `main.py`...

My `DocekrFile`:

```
FROM python:3.6-jessie
MAINTAINER Vladislav Ladenkov

WORKDIR folder1/folder2

COPY folder2/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY folder2/*.py ./

?? how to link volume ??

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py", "@??volume??"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a folder-name to map the volume:
`docker run MyImage -v /home/path/:/folder1/folder2/`
So now /home/path folder on the host machine is mounted to /folder1/folder2 inside the container.

Then just pass the path of the conf file as seen within the container to the cmd.
`ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py", "/folder1/folder2/myconf.conf"]`

Comment: hmm, can i do the same thing, but for the file?
`/home/path/myconf.conf:/folder1/folder2/myconf.conf`

Comment: According to this post you can map a file. i have not tried it though.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248198/how-to-mount-a-single-file-in-a-volume