# docker-compose creates directory instead of file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to setup my home server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) using some docker containers and docker-compose. While trying to setup the "transmission-rss" I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:577:in `initialize': Is a directory @ io_fillbuf - fd:5 /etc/transmission-rss.conf (Errno::EISDIR)
```

And when I went to check if the `transmission-rss.conf` file had been created a directory with the same name was created in its place.

I have to run the `docker-compose up` command using `sudo` so I don't know if this has anything to do with permissions.

Here is my current docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer
    volumes:
      - '/home/miguel/docker/portainer/data/:/data'
      - '/home/miguel/docker/portainer/socket/:/var/run/docker.sock'
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    restart: always
  transmission-rss:
    container_name: transmission-rss
    image: nning2/transmission-rss:latest
    volumes:
      - '/home/miguel/docker/transmission-rss/transmission-rss.conf/:/etc/transmission-rss.conf/'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The `portainer` container starts fine.

Thank you very much,
Miguel

Answer (score 10):

make sure that **files exist** in both side (inside host machine and inside container).

if one of them **not exist** then docker **create a directory instead of a file**

Comment: Is that right? I would expect that if the host file exists, but the container file does not, the host file would be mounted at the target location as a file.

Comment: @mikey check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66327349/10539792

Answer (score 5):

`- '/home/miguel/docker/transmission-rss/transmission-rss.conf/:/etc/transmission-rss.conf/'`

Please remove the trailing slashes (there are 2x!) and ensure `transmission-rss.conf` is a *file*, and not a *dir* on your host source.

To be slightly more comprehensive:

1. Follow this to avoid having to use `sudo` with docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall (*this is not the cause of your issue*, but it is annoying to have to preface every command with sudo, basically just need to add your user to the docker group).
2. Update `docker-compose.yml`, remove the trailing slashes from source and target for `transmission-rss.conf`.
3. Remove your existing volumes (`docker volume ls` + `docker volume rm volume_name`) after backing up your data, if needed.
4. On your *host* (the machine you are running the `docker-compose` commands from), make sure the *file exists*, and is **not** a *directory*
5. `docker-compose down`
6. `docker-compose build`
7. `docker-compose up`

Comment: Just to add to this; particularly the "make sure the file exists" part, double-check that you have the local (host) path correct. Sometimes a typo, extra subfolder, etc.. can slip by even the best of us.