# docker-compose create a directory instead of mounting the file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a very simple `docker-compose.yml` file where I use `nginx` and mounting a file as a volume.

But everytime I run the application, it is creating a directory `.htpasswd` without really mounting the `.htpasswd` file where I locally.

This is the `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3'
services:

  reverse:
    container_name: reverse
    hostname: reverse
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443      
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: can you please add a file listing for the `./nginx/` directory? (like adding the output for `ls -l`)

Comment: I believe this answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248198/how-to-mount-a-single-file-in-a-volume

Comment: @NoamYizraeli: here is the output `-rw-r--r--   1 jananath  staff    43  7 Mar 23:43 .htpasswd `

Comment: please try as suggested using the absolute path or mount relatively like now but the entire host nginx directory to `conf.d` inside the container

Comment: @NoamYizraeli, mounting an almost empty dir to conf.d will likely override/remove a file called default.conf which is probably not desired. From my expierence it is possible to mount a single file so long as the path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

by default if binded to a none existent path, docker will create a folder, the solution would be in your case to create the path before running your `docker-compose`

Answer (score -1):

How are you running Docker? here's an answer ...

**For Mac with Minikube/Hyperkit docker and Docker Compose**

Since I'm not using Docker Desktop any longer, I've experienced numerous issues similar to "docker in docker (dind)" paradigm with minikube...

1. **mount minikube**
2. **use absolute path**

e.g., easiest way was to mount the exact home path...

```sh
minikube mount $HOME:/Users/<you>

... keeps running...
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
volumes:
      - /Users/<you>/path/to/file.yaml:/somedir/file.yaml
```