# Run a SQL file when mysql's docker image first startup

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to run an init sql file at the first run of my MySQL:5.7.5 docker run.

I tired to run the following `docker run` command:

```bash
docker run -d -p 13306:3306 \
 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes \
 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=storagedb \
 -v storage.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/storage.sql \
 mysql:5.7.5
```

Then, I run `docker exec` into this container and use the following command `mysql -uroot -p`  into the mysql server.

Then I run `use storagedb` command to select the `-e MYSQL_DATABASE=storagedb` specified Database。

In the end, run `show tables` , I can't see the table I created in the SQL file。

The sql file's content is:

```sql
create database storagedb;
use storagedb;
CREATE TABLE `storage_tbl` (
                               `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                               `commodity_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                               `count` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
                               PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                               UNIQUE KEY (`commodity_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I try again with a Dockerfile, The`Dockerfile`'s content is:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
ADD storage.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/storage.sql
RUN chmod -R 775 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENV MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD yes
```

I build this Dockerfile to a new image `tmpMySQL`, Then i run this image and go into the container.

Now, i can see the database `storagedb` and the table `storage_tbl`. why?

I don't want to build a new docker image. I just want to startup a container by a mysql image and run an init `.sql` file with `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`!

Your guidance would be appreciated,
Thank you very much!

Comment: as I can see from the run command you are using storage 
have you tried to empty this storage before re-trying again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248198/how-to-mount-a-single-file-in-a-volume

Comment: @KerolosWilliam Do you mean the ``-v`` param  : ``-v storage.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/storage.sql \`` ?
This '``storage``' just is a .sql file name.

 Are you mean delete this -v param ?