# Rundeck user management with ECS Fargate [Community edition]

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, rundeck

I am managing users via the `realm.properties` file located in `home/rundeck/server/config` directory until an LDAP/AD solution is implemented. Everytime I updated the ECS/container task, the users I created using the previous container is deleted. I believe this is due to the lifecycle management of the container?

Is there any other way to manage users with Rundeck community?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `realm.properties` file as a [volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html) (supported by ECS). In that way, you can use a local / persistent custom `realm.properties` file. Take a look at this example:

The `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
services:
  rundeck:
    image: rundeck/rundeck:4.6.1
    environment:
      - RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=http://localhost:4440
    volumes:
      -  ./data/realm.properties:/home/rundeck/server/config/realm.properties
    ports:
      - "4440:4440"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The `realm.properties` local file (stored at the `data` directory, at the same level as the `docker-compose.yml` file).

```
admin:admin,user,admin
user:user,user
bob:bob,user,admin
```

Other options:

1. Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise") includes a GUI [User Management](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/user-management/user-mgmt.html#manage-local-users-enterprise) feature.
2. As you said, [LDAP](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap) / [AD](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#active-directory) integration.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Per AWS documentation, seems like `Docker volumes are only supported when using the EC2 launch type or external instances.` I am using the `Fargate` mode to run `Rundeck`. I will check if I can use the `EC2` launch type.

Should I need to make use of a Database to store this volume?
```"labels": { "database": "database_name" }```

Comment: I am asking about the database in regards to `./data/realm.properties:`. What is that path referring to?

Comment: Hi! That file is a local file, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260979/10426011