# Mounting a docker file on a remote VM results in a directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cicd

I am running a set of docker images within a docker environment in my CI/CD environment to run some integration tests. One of these images needs to be configured with an http call, but since curl is not allowed within docker I resorted to using a curl image to do my request from within the docker-compose environment.

```
# Relevant part of docker-compose
populate-smocker:
    image: curlimages/curl:8.3.0
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./mock-config.yaml
        target: /work/mock-config.yaml
    depends_on:
      mockserver:
        condition: service_started
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - 'curl -X POST --data-binary "@/work/mock-config.yaml" http://mockserver:3001/mocks -H "Content-Type: application/x-yaml"'
```

This works well locally, but not remotely - the mount ends up being an empty folder in the container. It seems like this happens because [the file I am mounting doesn't exist on the target VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73847749/6578141), but the answer doesn't give any solutions.

Comment: Does the `mock-config.yaml` file in fact exist on the remote system in the same directory as the Compose file?

Comment: You can't mount a local file to a remote container. A bind mount always refers to the filesystem of the computer on which the container is running. If you try to bind mount a file that does not exist...you get an empty directory. One option is to build a custom image and copy the file into the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it does

Comment: @larsks the file exists right beside the docker-compose file, are you saying that is not enough?

Comment: That is correct. Like I said, a bind mount always refers to the filesystem on the computer where Docker is running. If you're accessing a remote Docker instance via the HTTP API, you cannot bind mount files from your local filesystem.

Comment: My apologies, but I'm not sure I am following. The `mock-config.yaml` exists where I want to start the docker-compose, inside the remote docker system. So I'm not trying to use some file that I have locally on my own machine.

Comment: Okay, I may have misinterpreted your use of the phrase "remote" (I thought you were using a remote API), combined with the fact that you said, "the file I am mounting doesn't exist on the target VM". That suggests that everything I said in my earlier comments applies, but I'm not 100% I understand your setup. It's probably worth clarifying the question rather than replying via comments.